# how to convert spark datframe to pandas dataframe in AWS Glue

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I read in data from Snowflake into AWS Glue using spark, which results having a spark dataframe called df. After that I added the following to convert it to a pandas dataframe:

```
df2 = df.toPandas()
```

However, this is causing an error in AWS Glue.

Comment: Please provide details of error, metrics of data (size, columns, datatype etc.), sample code.

Comment: so the error message is: An error occurred while calling o96.collectToPython. SQL compilation error. The data is read via df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**snowflake_options).option("dbtable",snowflake_database+"."+snowflake_schema+"."+source_table_name).load().